# Impressora Fiscal

Tags: html, impressora

Preciso imprimir uma página HTML normal mas usando uma impressora fiscal (não sei se é esse o termo correto mas são aquelas impressoras menores que a gente vê em mercados).
Existe um "emulador" para se fazer esses testes?

Comment: Se for realmente uma impressora fiscal não tem como, verifique o modelo e se tem um lacre que normalmente identificam uma impressora fiscal.

Comment: Se você vai fazer isto pelo navegador padrão sem nenhuma ajuda extra no computador do usuário, só pode contar com o sistema de impressão do navegador. Não tem o que fazer. Sistemas *web* não são a solução para todos os problemas.

Comment: [Aqui](http://partners.bematech.com.br/bemacast/Paginas/post.aspx?idPost=6092) existe um emulador da Bematech para testes. Sei que funciona com aplicativos Desktop. Não sei se isso te ajuda muito.

Comment: Emulador da impressora Fiscal Bematech Térmica MP-4200 TH FI: http://partners.bematech.com.br/bemacast/Paginas/post.aspx?idPost=6092

Comment: Posso estar enganado mas alguma coisa me diz que você não quer um emulador, e o pessoal está levando isto literalmente. Não vejo como um emulador pode ajudar no problema. Acho que foi usado o termo errado, acho que queria algum software que permitisse imprimir nestas impressoras pelo navegador, que não é um emulador. Mas se o desejo é um emulador, não dá para responder sem saber que impressora está usando e só produzirá uma lista de respostas inúteis para o real problema.

Comment: Lhe ajudou? Você acha que pode aceitar a resposta?

Comment: Creio que dê pra fazer um sistema no backend por exemplo java comunicando com a impressora e através de serviços rest você comunicar da página HTML com o servidor backend. Para imprimir no backend você faz um formulário para ser impresso na impressora. Ainda não testei esta solução mas vou tentar fazer um sistema deste modelo.

Answer (score 6):

Se for usar uma impressora fiscal mesmo para fins fiscais, esqueça, a própria legislação impede o uso através de navegadores. Não de forma explícita, mas pelos requisitos para homologação do software.

Mesmo que seja uma impressora não fiscal ou seja usada para fins não fiscais ainda tem o problema de que a impressora só pode ser acessada pelo navegador. Ele tem controle sobre como mandar informações para a impressora. Mesmo assim, ainda tem o limite do sistema operacional.

Muitas vezes estas impressoras já são problemáticas para acessar de um aplicação *desktop* dadas as limitações do sistema operacional. Uma solução comum é escrever direto na porta.

Imagine a dificuldade de passar por isto com as limitações extras que o navegador impõe. Você pode tentar criar uma página, provavelmente sem HTML, e mandar imprimir e ver se consegue algum resultado. Mas duvido que dê certo. Fora isto pode pedir suporte para o fabricante mas acho que ele responderá o mesmo que estou respondendo aqui.

Fora isto é possível criar um aplicativo que acesse a impressora para o usuário acessar. Eventualmente ele pode se comunicar com o navegador mas acho que esta solução costuma ser ruim. Na maioria das vezes é mais fácil fazer uma aplicação *desktop* que resolva todo o problema. Aplicações *web* não resolvem todos os problemas, [um martelo não trabalha bem com um parafuso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

Até o momento desconheço uma forma de resolver este problema de outra forma. E é algo que já procurei bastante.

E dependendo do que seja a definição de uma página HTML normal também não vai conseguir imprimir neste tipo de impressora mesmo que tenha acesso direto a ela. Essas impressoras não costumam ser capazes de imprimir coisas sofisticadas como uma página HTML.

Provavelmente não é o que você quer, mas é possível fazer o trabalho de impressão no servidor sem envolver HTML na impressão em si, aí você tem controle total como se fosse uma aplicação *desktop*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

A Bematech possui emuladores para suas impressoras. A Epson também. A Daruma, até onde sei, não possui emulador. Você tem que fazer seus testes com uma impressora física. Não sei quanto às demais fabricantes.

Eu colocaria os links aqui, mas os links vem e vão. Estariam quebrados em um ano ou dois. É mais eficiente buscá-los quando você precisar.

Lembre-se de que cada impressora possui sua própria API. Você precisará desenvolver um código diferente para cada impressora.

Outro ponto a considerar é que pelo menos com as três fabricantes mencionadas, não adianta mandar código HTML para ela esperando que saia formatado no papel. Você vai ter que utilizar o código de formatação próprio de cada impressora.

E pra terminar... Se você deixar de entregar um cupom fiscal a um cliente porque o seu código usa o emulador em produção ao invés de imprimir de verdade, você vai preso em pouco tempo.