# Impressão com JavaScript e ActiveX

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, activex

Estou precisando realizar impressão a partir de uma aplicação web, acredito que terei que fazer isso com JavaScript e também pelo o que pesquisei talvez terei que fazer isso com ActiveX.

Eu já tentei usar `window.print()` com JavaScript mas abre aquela janela pedindo para escolher a impressora, no meu caso a impressão tem que ser feita de forma direta, sem interação do usuário.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode garantir que o site vai rodar apenas no Internet Explorer? Lembrando que ele já é um software legado e terá atualizações limitadas. O novo navegador da Microsoft é o Edge. Você pode conviver com isto?

Comment: Sim, a aplicação irá rodar apenas no IE.

Comment: O que você precisa imprimir? É algum conteúdo da página ou arquivos armazenados no servidor?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Na web padrão não é possível fazer isto. Falo mais sobre isto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53727/101).

Com ActiveX é possível mas ele só roda no Internet Explorer, um navegador em fim de linha. O novo navegador da Microsoft é o Edge, que fará o IE receber bem menos atenção, ou mesmo será quase abandonado.

Certamente existem outro *plugins* para resolver a questão em outros *browsers*, mas é algo tão complicado que não vale o esforço. Lembrando que é raro alguém instalar algo só para acessar um *site*. As pessoas já estão se revoltando de ter que instalar Java para acessar o seu banco.

Um *applet* Java poderia fazer o mesmo mas tentando usar o que foi indicado na pergunta:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print Test</title>
    <script language="VBScript">
        sub Print()
            OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
            OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
            OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
            call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
        End Sub
        document.write "<object id='WB' width='0' height='0' classid='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <object id="WebBrowser1" width="0" height="0" classid="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"> </object>
    <a href="#" onclick="Print()">Clique aqui para imprimir</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/ActiveX.html).

Retirado dessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12625594/221800).

Comment: Um detalhe é que estou usando Asp.Net MVC, tem como usar vbscript neste tipo de aplicação?

Comment: Tem, claro, o código gerado pelo ASP.Net MVC pode ter qualquer coisa que você quiser, até coisas inválidas em um navegador.

Comment: @EdmarMunhoz resolveu ou ajudou resolver?