# Transferir arquivo se servidor para cliente e enviar para LPT1

Tags: javascript, html5, visual-basic-6, funções

Preciso de ajuda com uma função que faça o seguinte:

- Tenho um arquivo `.txt` no disco `C:` do servidor
- Enviar este arquivo `.txt` para uma máquina cliente
- Enviar o conteúdo desde `.txt` para a porta `LPT1` do cliente

Atualmente utilizando o vb.NET já faço isso, mas preciso mudar o modo, afinal, de que jeito é feito hoje:

Uma função cria o arquivo no servidor e popula ele com informações (de 10 à 15 linhas), depois esta função chama um script que possui um objeto `ActionXObject` que cria o arquivo na máquina cliente, lê o arquivo no servidor e a cada linha escreve-a no .txt do cliente e após finalizar ele manda para a porta `LPT1`.

Hoje isto **funciona** desta forma no **IE** (uso na versão 11), mas **preciso** que funcione no **Chrome** e **FireFox**, **que não possuem suporte ao ActiveX**. Há algum substituto para o mesmo? Posso fazer de outra forma?

Comment: pode postar o código que você utiliza hoje?

Comment: Outra que responde bem: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53722/101